# Display data using JSON server in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to fetch some data from this json file :

```
//db.json
{

    "percents": [
        {
            "id": "x3m1",
            "value": 1.05
        },
        {
            "id": "x6m1",
            "value": 1.1
        },
        {
            "id": "x9m1",
            "value": 1.15
        },
        {
            "id": "x12m1",
            "value": 1.2
        },
        {
            "id": "x3m2",
            "value": 1.04
        },
        {
            "id": "x6m2",
            "value": 1.08
        },
        {
            "id": "x9m2",
            "value": 1.12
        },
        {
            "id": "x12m2",
            "value": 1.16
        },
        {
            "id": "x3m3",
            "value": 1.03
        },
        {
            "id": "x6m3",
            "value": 1.06
        },
        {
            "id": "x9m3",
            "value": 1.09
        },
        {
            "id": "x12m3",
            "value": 1.12
        }
    ]
}
```

I launched a json server on a different port on "http://localhost:8000/percents" and created an api like this:

```
//api.js
import axios from "axios";
export const getValues = async () => {
return await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/percents");  
};
```

and here is my main function :

```
//App.js
import "./App.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getValues } from "./api";

function App() {

  const [values, setValues] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadPercents();

  },[]);
  const loadPercents = () => getValues().then((v) => setValues(v.data));

  console.log(values);
  const fv = values.filter(x => x.id === "x3m1")
  console.log(fv[0].value);
  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto">
      <h1 className="text-4xl">Configuration</h1>
      <table>
        <tbody>


        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The problem is that when I started the project the first time it worked and the value was displayed in the console after that when I save I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
App
E:/mouadh/projects/hello - Copie/hello1/src/App.js:20
  17 | //const loadBands = () => getBands().then((b) => setBands(b.data));
  18 | console.log(values);
  19 | const fv = values.filter(x => x.id === "x3m1")
> 20 | console.log(fv[0].value);
     | ^  21 | //console.log(bands);
  22 | //console.log(values[0].value)
  23 | return (
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
//api.js
import axios from "axios";
export const getValues = async () => {
    const {data} = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/percents");  
return data
};
```

in your App.js

```
  const [values, setValues] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadPercents();
  },[]);
  const loadPercents = () => getValues().then((v) => setValues(v));

console.log(values) 
...
```

Use `optional` chaining like this just in case axios is still fetching data from an api

```js
const fv = values?.filter(x => x?.id === "x3m1")

// chsck what are you getting from the array fv by 

console.log(fv) 
  console.log(fv[0]?.value);
```